# What is the origin of hazak u'baruch?

Tags: minhag, tefilla, synagogue, torah-service, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern

Hazak u'barukh is a phrase commonly said after one does something in the synagogue (e.g., after an aliyah). What is its origin?

Comment: Do you mean these specific words, or the general practice of congratulatory remarks?

Answer (score 14):

The Rema [139:11](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&st=&pgnum=43) says To say Chazak from the passuk in Yehoshua that says Chazak vametz .The passuk before it says that Torah should not leave your mouth and it will be a blessing for you. So there are those who say Chazak u'baruch and others answer Chazak vametz.

The Kaf Hachaim [139:56](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41181&st=&pgnum=264&hilite=) brings down the minhag to say Chazak U'baruch from this Rema.

Comment: Yehoshua 1:8 which is right before passuk 9 says if when Torah does not leave your mouth then you will be blessed ,hence the blessing Chazak u'baruch

Comment: +1, sounds plausible, but do you have a source that indicates that that's the source, too, for the "_uvaruch_" part?

Comment: Are you sure he's not taking about the 'Chazak Chazak Venitchazak' at the end of each sefer?

Comment: @DoubleAA that is a Levush this Rema can be the source for it .I think the Rema is talking about finishing a Sefer but I am almost sure this is where the minhag saying after every Aliya came from. The Aruch Hashulchan 139:15 says to say Chazak Chazak chazak = Moshe.

Comment: sam, re _Kaf Hachayim_, nice find, but I don't see that he bases "_uvaruch_" on the _pasuk_.

Comment: @msh210 well he bases it off the Rema who bases it off the passuk.